# Cannot launch application with GDBServer. with hybrid app

Tags: debugging, tizen, hybrid

I have a tizen hybrid app with web app and native service.
When I try debug it I get an error:

```
Cannot launch application with GDBServer.
The application (vA7QHuj6iF) is not running on 192.168.1.162:26101
```

When I build new native service it debugs normaly but when I link it to web app I get this error again.

Any ideas how can I debug hybrid app?

Comment: Clear logs of your system, sometimes firewall is the problem so check it also. Reset your device. Check port manually which process binding with it.

Comment: I don't understand about logs. How can I clear them.

Answer (score 1):

Please try uninstalling the service app(which is packaged with web app) before you start debugging. After that try Debug As option.